# Error con fecha laravel 7 000000Z

Tags: vue.js, php7, laravel-6, laravel-7, momentjs

Hace poco actualice de Laravel 6 a la V7, y tengo un componente Vue que se encarga de mostrar el log en el siguiente formato de fecha: **YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s** / **2021-10-08 18:28:32**

Entonces hasta ese punto funciono de maravilla con la v6, y hasta hoy me empezó a mostrar la fecha de esta forma: **2021-10-04T18:47:33.000000Z**.

Es correcto pero solo ocupo hasta los segundos, no la zona horaria, utilice el date format de momentjs pero al parecer no lo respeta y se imprime con los 0;

Pensé que era el moment.js y revise la documentación y esta conforme a la documentación, entonces el único cambio que hice fue a la v7 de Laravel.

También verifique en la base de datos y se inserta tal cual *YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s*  el punto es cuando entra en el Query de Laravel, y procesa los datos:

**Los recibe así: 2021-10-08 18:28:32**

```
$timeline = $user->elogbook()->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();;
```

**Y los retorna así: 2021-10-08T18:27:32.000000Z**

Encontré que para solucionarlo había que agregar esto en el modelo:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

lo intente pero me sigue apareciendo igual, alguna alternativa o ejemplo de modelo por si lo agregue mal:

Modelo User función:

```
public function elogbook() {
        return $this->hasMany(Logbook::class, 'executor_id');
    }
```

Modelo Timelog funcion

```
public function executor() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'executor_id');
    }
```

Comment: Eloquent automáticamente crea un objeto Carbon la propiedad updated_at del modelo al seleccionar esa columna. Probablemente ese objeto Carbon se pasa al string con el formato que muestras, cuando el modelo se serializa en a matriz o un JSON. Prueba definir la propiedad $dateFormat en el modelo como está explicado [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#timestamps), pero con el formato que requieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 7 usa un nuevo formato de serialización de fecha cuando se usa el método *toArray* o *toJson* en modelos Eloquent.

Anteriormente, las fechas serían serializados en un formato como el siguiente:

```
2019-12-02 20:01:00.
```

Fechas serializan con el nuevo formato aparecerá como:

```
2019-12-02T20:01:00.283041Z
```

Tenga en cuenta que las fechas ISO-8601 siempre se expresan en UTC.

Si desea seguir usando el comportamiento anterior, puede anular el serializeDate método en su modelo:

```
use DateTimeInterface;

/**
 * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
 *
 * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
 * @return string
 */
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Ingrese el fragmento anterior en los modelos donde quiere que aparezca la fecha ( 2019-12-02 20:01:00. ) en ese formato, de esa manera anulara la serialización de fechas tras la nueva actualización.

[Más info aquí en la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization)